# querydsl how to build predicate to compare columns among each other

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I want to do following
`select column1,column2 from table where column1=column2`
How to do it in querydsl? I have code below but it binds `key=value`

Comment: I need something like path.eq(path)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List <BooleanExpression> getAddressBooleanExpressions (String type, Class<?> clazz) {
        List <BooleanExpression> booleanExpressions = new ArrayList<BooleanExpression>();
        PathBuilder<?> entityPath = new PathBuilder(clazz, type);
        BooleanExpression expression1 = entityPath.get("column1").eq(entityPath.get("column2"));
        BooleanExpression expression2 = entityPath.get("columnA").eq(entityPath.get("columnB"));
        BooleanExpression expression3 = entityPath.get("columnX").eq(entityPath.get("columnZ"));
        BooleanExpression expression4 = entityPath.get("physicalAddress" ).eq(entityPath.get("mailingAddress" ));        
        booleanExpressions.add(expression1);
        booleanExpressions.add(expression2);
        booleanExpressions.add(expression3);
        booleanExpressions.add(expression4);
        return booleanExpressions;      
    }
```